# rhea amqp ActiveMQ Artemis connection error

Tags: amqp, activemq-artemis, bun, rhea

I am starting Apache ActiveMQ Artemis 2.32.0 using a Docker container:

```
docker run --name activemq-artemis-2.32.0-alpine -p 61616:61616 -p 8161:8161 -p 5672:5672 --rm apache/activemq-artemis:2.32.0-alpine
```

Then I'm trying to connect to it using [rhea](https://github.com/amqp/rhea) client using this example code:

```js
var container = require('rhea');

container.on('message', function (context: any) {
    console.log(context.message.body);
    context.connection.close();
});
container.once('sendable', function (context: any) {
    context.sender.send({body:'Hello World!'});
});
var connection = container.connect({'port':5672, host: 'localhost', username:'artemis', password: 'artemis' });
connection.open_receiver('examples');
connection.open_sender('examples');
```

but I keep getting these message on the client side:

```
[connection-1] disconnected 
[connection-1] disconnected 
[connection-1] disconnected 
[connection-1] disconnected
```

and these on the broker side:

```
2024-03-26 19:36:31,132 ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ224088: Timeout (10 seconds) on acceptor "amqp" during protocol handshake with /192.168.65.1:60070 has occurred.
2024-03-26 19:36:41,256 ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ224088: Timeout (10 seconds) on acceptor "amqp" during protocol handshake with /192.168.65.1:60071 has occurred.
2024-03-26 19:36:51,469 ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ224088: Timeout (10 seconds) on acceptor "amqp" during protocol handshake with /192.168.65.1:60072 has occurred.
2024-03-26 19:37:01,891 ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ224088: Timeout (10 seconds) on acceptor "amqp" during protocol handshake with /192.168.65.1:60073 has occurred.
```

Connecting using Java `org.apache.qpid.jms.JmsConnectionFactory` works fine.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: The same error: `[connection-1] disconnected`

Comment: Should I open a ticket on the `rhea` GH page? Thx

Comment: Is there a JS amqp alternative to `rhea`? Thx

Comment: I believe that rhea is the only actively maintained AMQP 1.0 Javascript client.

Comment: FWIW, the `AMQ224088` error on the broker means that a client established a network connection to the broker, but didn't complete a protocol handshake.

Comment: I think opening a ticket on the rhea GitHub project page is a fine idea. Looking at the `rhea` tag I see that there are **0** watchers which means you aren't likely to get any help on it here.

Comment: The code runs fine with `node` so the problem appears related to using `bun`.